# Performance issues in T-SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which provides me daily inventory status. I.e Inventory Item X, on a particular date had Y amount of quantity. I have created a function to obtain the purchase price on a particular day based on the last purchases.

When I run the query on the dailyinventorystatus table it completes within 3 minute for date > 2014-01-01. However, when I add in the function as a subquery it causes huge performance issues. It has been over 1.5 hours and the query is still running.

How do I improve this?

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    RWReports.dbo.FindPurchasePrice(InventoryKey, Date , warehouse) as SalesPurchasePrice
FROM  
    DailyInventoryStatus
WHERE 
    Warehouse IN ('NYC,', 'CHICAGO', 'CHINA', 'ATLANTA')
    AND Date >= '2014-01-01'
```

Here is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FindPurchasePrice] 
    (@InventoryKey varchar(8), @InDate Date , @Warehouse varchar(30))
RETURNS REAL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @oPurchasePrice AS REAL ;

    SELECT TOP (1) 
        @oPurchasePrice = UnitPurchasePrice 
    FROM 
        PurchaseTransactions 
    WHERE 
        InventoryKey = @InventoryKey 
        AND TransactionDate <= @InDate 
        AND Warehouse = @Warehouse 
    ORDER BY  
        TransactionDate DESC; 

    IF @oPurchasePrice IS NULL 
       SELECT
           @oPurchasePrice = mw.cost 
       FROM 
           Rentalworks.dbo.masterwh mw 
       JOIN 
           Rentalworks.dbo.warehouse w ON w.warehouseid = mw.warehouseid
                                       AND mw.masterid = @InventoryKey 
                                       AND w.warehouse = @Warehouse;

    RETURN @oPurchasePrice;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Expressing the logic as a single query rather than using a function might fix your performance problems.

Comment: Scalar functions are horrible for performance. The way you build this it has to run your function for every single row in the result set. Converting to an inline table valued function would help. But you have to be able to get the result in a single query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you please elaborate on this. How would it be possible do to this via query to obtain the purchase cost on a particular day based on the the last purchase transaction. I don't see that being possible without a stored procedure. Even then there may be performance issues.

Comment: How many rows are returned - just a few ones or lots of them?

Comment: @jarlh the query without using the function has over 1.8 million rows. But without the function, the select takes less than 3 minutes.

Comment: So the function is executed 1.8 million times...

Comment: @jarlh now that you put it that way. That sounds horrifying. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you really need a report with 1.8 million rows every day? Who is going to look through that??

Comment: @SeanLange It is being utilized to create a summarized report. But I still need the underlying daily cost and quantity to calculate the value.

Comment: Just a tangential comment but `real` is not a good type to be using for prices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you could possibly convert this into an inline table valued function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FindPurchasePrice] 
(
    @InventoryKey varchar(8)
    , @InDate Date 
    , @Warehouse varchar(30)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS

RETURN
    SELECT ISNULL(pt.UnitPurchasePrice ,mw.cost) AS PurchasePrice
    FROM Rentalworks.dbo.masterwh mw 
    JOIN Rentalworks.dbo.warehouse w on w.warehouseid = mw.warehouseid
        AND mw.masterid = @InventoryKey 
        AND w.warehouse = @Warehouse
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) UnitPurchasePrice 
        FROM PurchaseTransactions 
        WHERE InventoryKey = @InventoryKey 
        AND TransactionDate <= @InDate 
        AND Warehouse=@Warehouse 
        ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC
    ) pt
```

I of course can't test this but it syntax checks fine.

Now to include that in your original select statement you would do something like this.

```
SELECT dis.*
    , fp.PurchasePrice
FROM DailyInventoryStatus dis
CROSS APPLY dbo.FindPurchasePrice(dis.InventoryKey, dis.Date, dis.warehouse) fp
WHERE Warehouse IN ('NYC,', 'CHICAGO', 'CHINA', 'ATLANTA')
AND Date >= '2014-01-01'
```

Comment: Another opportunity to improve performance - invent something better than varchar keys. (to @devista)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to re-write without the function by incorporating all the logic into a single query:

```
with data as (
    select
        dis.*, pt.TransactionDate, pt.UnitPurchasePrice,
        row_number() over (
            partition by dis.InventoryKey, dis.Warehouse
            order by TransactionDate desc
        ) as TransNumber
    from
        DailyInventoryStatus dis left outer join
        PurchaseTransactions pt
            on      pt.InventoryKey = dis.InventoryKey
                and pt.Warehouse = dis.Warehouse
                and pt.TransactionDate < dis.Date
        where dis.Date >= ?
)
select
    *,
    coalesce(
        UnitPurchasePrice,
        (
            select mw.cost
            from
                Rentalworks.dbo.masterwh mw inner join
                Rentalworks.dbo.warehouse w
                    on w.warehouseid = mw.warehouseid
            where mw.masterid = data.InventoryKey
                and w.warehouse = data.Warehouse
         )
    ) as PurchasePrice
from data
where TransNumber = 1
```

Comment: What does TransNumber = 1 mean?

Comment: Look in the first part of the query. It identifies the rows that are first in descending order by transaction date for each inventory key and warehouse.